# supabase auth helpers ui with Google social login, how to restrict users to domain

Tags: node.js, oauth, sveltekit, supabase

Google offer a 'hd' parameter to restrict oauth access to domain. Anyway to set this when using supabase auth helpers  / auth UI?

Answer (score 1):

You can set policies/custom claims for the domain, then block users that doesn't have rights from getting into the app.

Here's an example limiting based on the domains from the [Supabase docs](https://supabase.com/docs/learn/auth-deep-dive/auth-policies):

```
create policy "Only Blizzard staff can update leaderboard"
  on my_scores
  for update using (
    right(auth.jwt() ->> 'email', 13) = '@blizzard.com'
  );
```